# Using LET to get a group in order to get the total (SUM) of quantity?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Name Type Quantity
 A    1    2
 A    2    3
 B    1    3
```

Defined by the class Items with the three fields (string Name, int Type, double Quantity).

This is stored in a List< Items >  called Summary.

What I need to do is get the SUM of QUANTITY for a specific NAME, but this logic lies within a much larger LINQ query, so I am trying to find a way to do it using LET statements.

Knowing that I am looking for the total quantity for a (Name = TargetName) I was trying to do something like this:

```
let items = Summary.Where(y => y.Name == TargetName).GroupBy.(z => z.Name)
```

and now I can use items to get my sum as follows:

```
TotalQuantity = items.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
```

But this doesn't work,  get the following error:

Error   2   'System.Linq.IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'Quantity' and no extension method 'Quantity'

Which is also the case when I do x. there is no option for Quantity in intelisense (it gives me options as if this was a list).

Any ideas?
I assume this is a newb mistake (I am new to LINQ).
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to sum for a specific name, you just call:

```
TotalQuantity =  Summary.Where(y => y.Name == TargetName)
                        .Sum(x => x.Quantity);
```

and needless o use `GroupBy` on this case. But if you want access `SUM` very often with different names, you might think to use `GroupBy` and then `ToDictionary` to improve performance:

```
var sumDic = Summary.GroupBy(z => z.Name)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                                  g => g.Sum(x => x.Quantity));
```

So, if you want get quantity of any `Name`, just use `sumDic`:

```
var result = sumDic[TargetName];
```